# Who manipulated Kylo Ren to turn to the Dark Side when he was the son of Han Solo & Princes Leia?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

In *Star Wars: The Force Awakens* we can see that Kylo Ren is the son of Han Solo and Princes Leia. Even though his parents are part of the good side Kylo turned to the Dark Side & wanted to be the next Darth Vader.

So my question is: Does the movie mention anything about how Kylo Ren turned to Dark Side even though his parents were good, and who manipulated him?

Comment: Downvoted for a total absence of research effort. Snoke's influence is mentioned multiple times in the Force Awakens and the subsequent films in the series

Comment: The obvious reply is .. Have you even seen the movies?  But if you haven't, don't bother, you're not missing anything worthwhile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**It was Snoke that corrupted Ben Solo while he was training with Luke Skywalker and turned him into Kylo Ren.**

Kylo's father, Han, knew that Snoke was only using him for his power.

> Han: That's what Snoke wants you to believe, but it's not true. My son is alive.
>
> Ren: No. The Supreme Leader is wise.
>
> Han: Snoke is using you for your power. When he gets what he wants, he'll crush you. You know it's true.
>
> <sub>Han Solo and Kylo Ren, *The Force Awakens*</sub>

Snoke confirms this to Kylo that the plan was to turn him into the next Darth Vader because of the Skywalker bloodline.

> Hmm. The mighty Kylo Ren. When I found you, I saw what all masters live to see: Raw, untamed power... and beyond that, something truly special. The potential of your bloodline. A new Vader. Now, I fear I was mistaken.
>
> <sub>Snoke, *The Last Jedi*</sub>

Luke sensed  this during his training of Ben but acted irrationally and drove Ben straight into Snoke's arms.

> I saw darkness. I sensed it building in him. I'd seen it in moments during his training. But then I looked inside, and it was beyond what I ever imagined. Snoke had already turned his heart.
>
> <sub>Luke Skywalker, *The Last Jedi*</sub>

Leia blamed Snoke as well and thought Kylo could be brought back to the light and be Ben again, but Han wasn't so sure.

> Han Solo : We lost our son. Forever.
>
> Leia : No. It was Snoke. He seduced our son to the dark side. But we can still save him. Me. You.
>
> Han Solo : If Luke couldn't reach him, how could I?
>
> Leia : Luke is a Jedi. You're his father. There is still light in him, I know it.
>
> <sub>Leia Organa and Han Solo, *The Force Awakens*</sub>